# Is it possible to leverage Office 365 API and edit Office doc (e.g. xls, doc) directly with the Office 365 editor?

Tags: rest, wysiwyg, office365

Is it possible to leverage Office 365 API and edit Office doc (e.g. xls, doc) directly with the Office 365 editor?

We are building a doc management system for a client and it would be very nice for them to directly be able to edit their Office documents in the browser without leaving their system.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: nope.. and also never did the project the way it is described here

Comment: If possible, can you describe how you solved it as we've got a similar issue with a client's system we developed for them. We've got a few alternatives, just wondering how you crossed the particular bridge - Will understand if you can't / don't want to answer though.